# Cucumber-JVM : How to read feature, scenario and step at run time

Tags: selenium, cucumber-jvm

I am creating a automation framework using cucumber+Java+Selenium. I have created customized report, need above said detail to print it in report.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Try to show some code and point to something.  Open ended questions cannot have (definite) answers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will answer your question, as it's too vague (as Bala says above), but Cucumber--JVM can output the test results in a JSON file, which can then be read & used in subsequent steps - see the Cucumber Reporting and Cucumber Performance plugins on Github for details & examples